# SQL Query, "Selecting" derived information

Tags: mysql, select

So I have the following tables

```
USER (**User_ID**, name, password)

MESSAGE (**Sender_ID**(FK), **Recipient_ID**(FK), message)
// Sender and Recipient both reference User_ID
```

I want to write a statement that returns the number of inbox messages for each user. I know that what I need to do is tally each time a user is listed as a Recipient and display those results, but I'm only a SQL novice and am not sure how to format the statement to yield that result.

Comment: Write a `JOIN`. If you don't know how to do that, you need to learn. SO is not a substitute for learning what you're doing first.

Comment: Learn how to use the `COUNT()` aggregate function and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think that's what I was looking for, I know it was going to be a JOIN but I wasn't sure exactly how to extract/display the information I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
select u.USER_ID, u.name, count(m.RECIPIENT_ID) as InboxCount
from USER u
left join MESSAGE m on u.USER_ID = m.RECIPIENT_ID
group by u.USER_ID, u.name
```

Comment: I knew it would need to be a left join, The COUNT function and the 'as' keyword were the pieces I was missing. Thanks!